# Is it possible to hide the text in a textbox?

Tags: text, textbox, hide

I've searched online, but I can't find the answer, so I am not sure if it is possible. Is it possible to hide the text in a text box, not the actual text box?

Thanks.

Comment: Explain the context of your question and add the appropriate tags (css, html)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague; I will assume you mean the HTML `Textbox`. And when you say hide, I assume you want it non-visible only as opposed to (for example) moving the value of the textbox to something like [`<input type ="hidden">`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden).

Yes, you can do this with `CSS`

Just set the `color` to the same as the `textbox` background.

So, assuming your textbox background colour is white,

```
<input type="text" class="whiteText" />
```

and your CSS is simply

```
.whiteText
{
    color:#fff;
}
```